# Get count of related models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models, **Item** which represents a product, and **OnHand** which represents each individual serialized product. They are bound by a ForeignKey of **product_id**.

**Item Model:**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**OnHand Model:**

```
class OnHand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial
```

---

On my **Index** view, I have a table which shows these products and counts quanity. In order to do this, i need to count the amount of **OnHand** objects exist with a matching **product_id**.

**Index:**

```
def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    quanity = count_onhand(items)
    context = {
        'items':items,  
    }
    print(items)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**count_onhand:**

```
def count_onhand(items):
        for item in items:
                count = OnHand.objects \
                .filter(product_id=item.product_id) \
                .count()
```

Because these are going to the same view and need to maintain their order, I figured the best direction would be to append to the **Item** queryset then appending to a list I'll send back with the original Item, with the quanity appended.

EDIT: I've found the above wouldn't be a wise approach, but leaving it there for context.

What I want to do is get the count of all **OnHand** objects that are related to a given **Item**. `prefetch_related()` seems close to what I want, but appears to only work with many-to-many (to my knowledge).

I can use `OnHand.objects.filter(product_id=item.pk).count()`, but I'm unsure if this is the most standard approach.

Comment: I am reading an article now on prefetching, a little confused on it, but think it may be what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is get the count of all OnHand objects that are related to a given Item.

Just use query api:

```
some_item.onhand_set.count()
```

If you want the count for a set or items:

```
from django.db.models import Count
items = ( Item
         .objects
         .filter( some condition )
         .annotate(num_onhand=Count('onhand'))
         )
```

More samples at [django Aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations)